# CVS Access +Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, cvs

I have installed CVS server cvsnt-2.5.03.2382.msi. I am getting below error while connecting using eclipse

```
"I/O has been interrupted.Timeout while reading from input streamThe most likely cause of
 the interrupt is either an intermittent network failure or a communications timeout.The CVS communications timeout can be adjusted in the Team/CVS preferences.Another possible cause is the improper configuration of the "ext" connection method.The "ext" connection method can be configured on the Team/CVS/EXT Connection Method preference page".
```

What will be the problem?

Comment: I'm adding this as a comment because it's a bit snarky and not really constructive, but I am curious - why on earth are you still using CVS?

Comment: :) We are using this one for maintenance projects. For all others We are using Git. Ok Any solution for above one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in My environment variables as it is pointing to some other location of CVSROOT.Thanks